JMeter dynamic correlation assistance
I am new to Jmeter. I have been trying to perform recorded scripts on ServiceNow catalog item that I have created. I think I was able to correlate the x-User-Token from the login Sample to the later samples to avoid the unauthorized issue. But Still some samples with path: instance URL/amb are failing with error 400. The response body shows Sorry,page not found. Even if I try to manually seaerch that URL (/amb), it displays "sorry page not found". Then why is this sample getting recorded to begin with?
I have added a Cookie Manager to take care of the dynamic session IDs. Do you think that's enough? Could you tell me what else I should do to debug the test scripts?
If anyone has done this before, please tell me what all dynamic parameters would I need to correlate?
I have added a Cookie Manager to take care of the dynamic session IDs.
I was able to correlate the x-User-Token from the login Sample to the later samples to avoid the unauthorized issue.

You need to correlate all the parameters which are dynamic.
We cannot tell you which exactly as service now is highly customizable and we don't know details of your integration. Just record the same scenario twice and compare resulting JMeter .jmx test plans, all the values which will be different are a subject to correlation.
You can also give JMeter Auto Correlation plugin a try, there is a chance it will be able to detect all the necessary values.
